# Графики в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно создать подобный график средствами JS? Может быть библиотеку подскажете или это надо самому делать на Canvas?

Comment: https://www.scichart.com/javascript-chart/   .......  https://openbase.com/categories/js/best-javascript-graphics-libraries   ..... chartjs